# Show 'Retrieving Data' Message while filling the Datatable

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, infragistics

I want to show message on datagrid like 'Retrieving Data' while filling the datatable. Is there any chance to make it happen ?

Here is my code that filling the datatable;

```
public void getAlertGrid()

    {
            odaAlert = new OracleDataAdapter(getAlert, oradb); //odaAlert is Adapter
            odaAlert.Fill(dtAlert);  // dtAlert is Datatable
            ugAlert.DataSource = dtAlert;
    }
```

Comment: Use `Backgroundworker` or `Thread`

Comment: @IkramTurgunbaev Hi. What about tasks ?

Comment: Yes, you can use tasks too

Comment: @IkramTurgunbaev I actually used it but i wonder that how can implement it. Currently i am using; Task.Factory.StartNew(() => getAlertGrid()); However which part should i say 'Retrieving Data' ?

Comment: Can't you just put a panel containing a textbox over the top of the grid that gets shown before you start fetching data and hidden when finished? Seems like anything else it just complicating the matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @IkramTurgunbaev said you need to load data asynchronously and update the status bar. In the place where you call your getAlertGrid method do something like this:

```
private void MethodThatCallsGetAlertGrid()
{
    // Show the progress bar and set the style of progress bar to Marquee. This will show continiously scrolling block across progress bar, as you cannot know the current progress percent
    this.progressBar1.Visible = true;
    this.progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;

    // Start loading the data source async
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        this.getAlertGrid())
   .ContinueWith((antecedent) =>
    {
        // Set data source on UI thread. Remove the same row from your getAlertGrid method
        ugAlert.DataSource = dtAlert;

        // Hide the progress bar
        this.progressBar1.Visible = false;
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```